# count total volume by category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables 
Company_categories
companies 
daily_rates

I want to count total volume industry wise of all the company exist within the category of companies

for example category A contains 3 companies and category B contains 5 companies so I want to sum total volume of all 3 companies in category A and so on for all categories I tried to do so but I am confused how to do with 3rd table as of I am easily been able to count the companies contains in category but not sure how to count the volume of all companies exist in a category

my table structure

```
company_categories 
      id         name
+------------+----------+
|     1      |    A     |
|------------|----------|
|     2      |    B     |
|------------|----------|


companies 
      id         name      category
+------------+----------+-----------+
|     1      |    co 1  |      1    |
|------------|----------|-----------|
|     2      |    co 2  |      2    |
|------------|----------|-----------|
|     3      |    co 3  |      1    |
|------------|----------|-----------|

daily_stock_rates
      id         traded_volume     company_id  
+------------+------------------+---------------+
|     1      |    40            |      1        |
|------------|------------------|---------------|
|     2      |    80            |      2        |
|------------|------------------|---------------|
|     3      |    30            |      3        |
|------------|------------------|---------------|
```

here is my code

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT c.id category_id, c.name category_name, com.id, com.category count( dsr.total_traded_volume ) total_volume
FROM company_categories c
INNER JOIN companies com ON c.id = com.category
LEFT JOIN daily_stock_rates dsr ON com.id = dsr.company_id
GROUP BY com.category
ORDER BY total_volume DESC LIMIT 10");

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     echo $data['category_name'] . ": .".$data['total_volume'];
     echo "<br />";
 }
```

Can Anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joint twice to get all the rates related to the category

```
SELECT cat.name, SUM(rat.traded_volume) volume
FROM company_categories cat
JOIN companies comp ON comp.category = cat.id
JOIN daily_stock_rates rat ON rat.company_id = comp.id
GROUP BY cat.name
ORDER BY volume DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Most important diff to your query:

- you need SUM(), not COUNT()
- select only what you asked: volume by category. You cannot select
  names of companies alongside (what company you would want to see
  there anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the join you got wrong, it's the select list and the group by clause.

First of all, if you want the total of the volume, then use `sum()`, not `count()`. Also, do not include so many fields in the select list if you want the total by category:

```
SELECT c.id category_id, c.name category_name, sum( dsr.total_traded_volume ) total_volume
FROM company_categories c
LEFT JOIN companies com ON c.id = com.category
LEFT JOIN daily_stock_rates dsr ON com.id = dsr.company_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total_volume DESC LIMIT 10
```